# How to simulate browser timeout of ajax request?

Tags: ajax, timeout

I'm trying to secure my web application against timeouts of ajax requests.
To do it, I obviously need to simulate such a timeout.

From what I've found here:
http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.connect.timeout#Background
the firefox timeout is system-dependent and from what I've found here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/181050 the IE timeout period is 60 minutes by default.

So I see the following ways to simulate a timeout:

- make the server wait 60 minutes (yuck ;))
- change the IE timeout period to a smaller value (which requires registry changes)
- configure a proxy between the client and the server and make it timeout

All the ways above seem like an overkill to me. Does anyone know an easier way (possibly on a different browser)?
Thanks!

Comment: You can't specify a timeout in your ajax request ? And then simply put a sleep(timeout+1000); in your server file to test it.

Comment: Since this is just "for testing", I would opt to use an existing proxy designed for this.

Comment: @PaulDinh seems like a nice idea, but it doesn't work for me cause I'm testing on localhost...

Comment: @NeeL also seems good to me... This would work only on IE8 (only there timeout is supported AFAIK) but it sounds like a plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually the easiest way for me was simulate the timeout by setting ReceiveTimeout in registry HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings
as described here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/181050

Darshan's solution might also work, but I just tested the above. Thank you all for help!

Answer (score 12):

Wouldn't it be much easier to simply set the ajax timeout to 1 millisecond. Even on localhost it will always timeout at that value. This is the method I always use. The only thing you don't exercise with this approach is the actual "feel" that your preferred timeout period gives to the end user (ie, does 3 seconds feel long, is 2 seconds too short). But if you're just looking to exercise the code under the error response this does the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

whats harm in setting KeepAliveTimeout in registry
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\InternetSettings ?

More information can be found here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/181050

Comment: Well, not much, but you need to restart the system then and if I wanted to simulate it again in the future I would need to restart again etc. But I do agree that it's the easiest way of the 3 mentioned solutions.

Comment: `jQuery.ajax({
 type: "post",
 url: Json,
 dataType: "text",
 timeout: (30 * 1000),
 data: {'id': id, 'sql':sql, 'p':ps, 'project':psplit[0], 'task':psplit[1]},
 
 success: function(d) { // do something },
 
 error: function( resp, status, error ){
  if(status) {
   if(status == 'timeout') alert('ERROR: There is a connection problem.\nPlease try again.\nIf the problem persists, please contact the Help Desk.');   
 }
 });  `    Here I have used timeout as 30 sec... call function may be Stored procedure put wait delay of 30 sec. and test ur timeout code... Hope this helps

Comment: thanks, looks nice, but I'm not using jquery. However, this can be simulated by the timeout XHR attribute under IE8.

Comment: @machinery And you can recreate a timeout using a setTimeout and doing an abort(); when the timer ticks on other browsers (if it is really not implemented)

Comment: @NeeL So it seems, but how do I know that what the browsers are doing when facing a timeout is calling abort()? I mean: how do I know that calling abort() is identical to a 'real' timeout?

Comment: @Darshan I have not tested your registry key, but I managed to simulate the timeout by setting ReceiveTimeout as described here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/181050. If you update your answer to use ReceiveTimeout, I'll mark it accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

It's simple, set the timeout to 10.

like this : `xhr.timeout = 10;`